# How to parse multiple XML (located in one xml file) in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm writing a xml to csv converter. I'm having a GUI which lets the user choose which XML-Tags he wants to convert. That is working fine so far but I stumpled across a problem:

I'm getting my data from another software. I thought I will get a XML with multiple XFA entrys for each document. But what I really get is an .xml document with multiple xml inside.

[.xml sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eLpq.png)

I am using the DocumentBuilder from Java, and (of course) getting an exeption (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException) as soon as it is at line 4 (beginning of new xml).

I know I could try to read the file as a .txt and split it so that I get multiple single xml files. But is there any other option where I could leave the file as it is and just edit the parser to work with it? (I will have up to 5.000 xml so I don't really want to generate 5.000 new files for that).

I'm sorry if I am just too blind to see an obvious answer.

Thank you!

This is my XMLReader code if that helps

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        //Build Document
        Document document = builder.parse(new File(path));

        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList nList = root.getChildNodes();
        
        XMLTagLookUp.visitChildNodes(nList);
```

Comment: You can enclose the documents with your own root tag. But then you have maybe problems with the doc type headers.